# Can I get {{link-to}} to specify which animation to use with ember fire?

Tags: ember.js, emberfire

I have left/right arrows on a page and I want to pick the animation without having to define a relationship between all the routes. Is it possible to set it on the `{{link-to}}`? Right now it's pretty brittle.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking, and I don't think it's possible to know what link was clicked from the transition it caused. However, I can think of two different ways to tackle your use case.

### Solution 1: metaprogramming

Make a list of your routes and generate transitions dynamically from it. Something like this:

```
// app/transitions.js
export default function() {

  const orderedRoutes = [
    'left-route',
    'center-route',
    'right-route',
  ];

  // See https://github.com/coleww/each-cons
  // where I pinched this from
  function eachCons(a, n) {
    var r = []
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - n + 1; i++) {
      r.push(range(a, i, n))
    }
    return r
  }
  function range (a, i, n) {
    var r = []
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      r.push(a[i + j])
    }
    return r
  }

  eachCons(orderedRoutes, 2).forEach(pair => {
    // `pair` will be each pair of consecutive routes
    // on our `orderedRoutes` list
    const left = pair[0];
    const right = pair[1];

    // For each pair, define a transition
    this.transition(
      this.fromRoute(left),
      this.toRoute(right),
      this.use('toLeft'),
      this.reverse('toRight')
    );
  });
}
```

Note that I only define transitions for adjacent routes. If you want to define a transition between `left-route` and `center-route`, you'll need to alter the algorithm to define new combinations.

### Solution 2: callback to `fromRoute`

The function `fromRoute` can not only take a string, but also a function. This function receives two parameters: the names of the initial and the final routes of a transition. In this function you can return `true` if the transition should apply, and `false` otherwise. See here:

http://ember-animation.github.io/liquid-fire/#/transition-map/route-constraints

You can use this function to decide whether you should be going left or right (as per your use case). See this:

```
// app/transitions.js
export default function() {

  // Names of the routes in the left-right succession
  const orderedRoutes = [
    'left-route',
    'center-route',
    'right-route',
  ];

  function isLeft(initial, destination) {
    const i0 = orderedRoutes.indexOf(initial);
    const i1 = orderedRoutes.indexOf(destination);

    if (i0 === -1 || i1 === -1) {
      // This is not one of the transitions
      // in the left-right succession
      return false;
    }

    if (i0 === i1) {
      // They are the same route
      return false;
    }

    // This will be `true` if the initial route
    // is "to the left" of the destination route
    return i0 < i1;
  }

  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute(isLeft),
    this.use('toLeft')
    this.reverse('toRight')
  );
}
```

In this example, for each transition we check the initial and the destination route. We see if they belong to the left-right succession, and whether the transition corresponds to a "left" or a "right". If it's a "left" we return true in the "toLeft" case. If it's a "right", we return true in the "toRight" case.